# React Bootstrap SweetAlert in React js not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to create a logout button with `sweetalert`. I created a logout function, and it worked perfectly without `sweetalert`. But when I add the `sweetalert` button it stops working.

Here is my code. please help me...

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';

class Hero extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            alert: null
        };
    }  

    showAlert = () => (
            this.setState = ({
                alert: (
                    <SweetAlert
                    title="Here's a message!"
                    onConfirm={this.props.handleLogout}
                    onCancel={this.onCancel}
                    showCancel={true}
                    focusCancelBtn={true}
                    />
                )
            })
            
        );

    render(){
        return (
            <section className = "hero">
                <nav>
                    <h2>Book Exchange</h2>
                    <button onClick = {() => this.showAlert()}>Logout</button>
                </nav>
            </section>
        );
    }
};
export default Hero;
```

My `handleLogout` function is below and it worked perfectly without `sweetalert`. I am using firebase for auth.

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  fire.auth().signOut()
};
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You have crafted a pretty good question, except for one regard: you should refrain yourself from just asking the community to help you. Instead, show what you have done; what errors you are getting; what would be the desired behaviour; etc. Then, precisely state your question. This will improve your chances of being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that instead of assigning `setState` with the new states, you should execute it as a function.

You can then, try rendering the alert conditionally, as follows:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';

class Hero extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            alert: false,
        };
    }  

    showAlert = () => {
      this.setState({
        alert: true,
      })
    };

    render(){
        return (
          <>
            <section className = "hero">
                <nav>
                    <h2>Book Exchange</h2>
                    <button onClick = {this.showAlert}>Logout</button>
                </nav>
            </section>
            { 
                this.state.alert && <SweetAlert
                    title="Here's a message!"
                    onConfirm={this.props.handleLogout}
                    onCancel={this.onCancel}
                    showCancel={true}
                    focusCancelBtn={true}
                    />
             }
            </>
        );
    }
};
export default Hero;
```